# Watin login without seeing the page

Tags: authentication, watin, google-signin

I want to do a automatic login on a web without seeing the page (it have to be transparent for the user). All have to by using c#.

I thought that maybe with watin i can do it. I can login into a web seeing it, but i wonder if i could do it without seeing it.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can **hide** the IE window with:

```
     Settings.Instance.MakeNewIeInstanceVisible = false;
     ie = new IE(true);
```

OR

```
    ie = new IE(true);
    ie.ShowWindow(NativeMethods.WindowShowStyle.Hide);
```

.

You can **minimize** the IE window with:

```
    ie = new IE(true);
    ie.ShowWindow(NativeMethods.WindowShowStyle.Minimize);
```

Comment: really thanks, i think that this could be perfect but... what if the browser isn't IE? I mean... there is some function to know which browser is using the user? Because i would like to do the login in the current browser. Thanks

Comment: ah, and my app is a website so this function of login will be in the server... so... the new browser are going to open on the server! How can i do it for the client side? Javascript? Watin can work with javascript?

Comment: I'm not sure that you have a clear understanding of WatiN and how/why you would use it.  I'd suggest going through the concept you're trying to accomplish and evaluate if WatiN is the correct tool.